# material ui modal slow and even crash

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I'm using Reactjs to create a table, the thing I want to do is every time I click one of the rows in the table, a modal will pop up and ask me if I want to print this row. I have added a modal using material-UI dialog, but it performs really bad, it's responded slowly and after a few click it will freeze the app and eventually crash it.
Could anyone suggest where the problem is? I tried to solve this for a day already, but still no progress.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {useState, setState} from 'react';
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/iconsStyle.js";
    import MaterialTable, {MTableHeader, MTableToolbar} from 'material-table';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import date from 'date-and-time';
    import AlertDialog from 'components/Modal/popover';
    import { useConfirm, ConfirmProvider } from 'material-ui-confirm';

    /**
     * Date Calculation
     */

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
        ...styles,
        typography: {
            padding: theme.spacing(2),
          },
          paper: {
            position: 'absolute',
            width: 400,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
            border: '2px solid #000',
            boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
            padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
          },
    }));




    //FUNCTION: Generates todays date and the requested picking terminal date in pacific time
        //OUTPUT: Todays date and the requested date for picking terminal   
    function ImportantDates(){
        var today = new Date(); 
        // var year = today.getFullYear();
        // var Month = today.getMonth()+ 1; //getMonth() can return 0, so +1 is needed.
        // var Day = today.getDate();
        const now = new Date();
        const day = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        //Get todays date and convert UTC to Pacific
        //Determine the start date day of the week
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
        var dayOfWeek = weekday[today.getDay()];

        //Monday through Wednesday
        var leapDay = 3;
            if(dayOfWeek === "Wednesday"){
                leapDay = 5;
            }
            //Skip the weekends
            if(dayOfWeek === "Sunday"){
                leapDay = 4;
            }
            if(dayOfWeek === "Saturday"){
                leapDay = 4;
            }
            if((dayOfWeek === "Thursday") || (dayOfWeek === "Friday")){
                leapDay = 5;
            }
        //How far ahead the picking terminal is looking
        var date_ = date.addDays(now, leapDay);
        date_ = date.format(date_, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        var dates ={
        "today": day,
        "requested": date_,
        }
        return dates;
    }


    // query for picking terminal 
    function getQuery(){
        const date = ImportantDates();
        const requested = date['requested'];
        const query = 
        `SELECT  work_orders.WOID, work_orders.endDate, work_orders.printed,
        work_orders.quantity, 
        work_orders.expedite, 
        work_orders.buildable,
        work_orders.startDate,
        work_orders.orderStatus,
        work_orders.createdDate,
        work_orders.productionLine, 
        work_orders.estTotalRunTime,
        work_orders.productionNotes,
        work_orders.productionStatus, 
        
        sales_orders.SOID,
        sales_orders.shipDate, 
        
        parts.partName, 
        parts.partDescription,
        
        customers.CID,
        customers.customerName
        
        
        FROM work_orders 
        
        LEFT JOIN sales_orders 
        ON work_orders.internalId  = sales_orders.internalId 
        
        LEFT JOIN parts 
        ON work_orders.partId  = parts.partId 
        
        LEFT JOIN customers 
        ON sales_orders.CID  = customers.CID
        WHERE orderStatus = 'Released' AND productionStatus = 'Approved' AND startDate <= '${requested}'
        ORDER BY expedite DESC, startDate ASC, shipDate IS NULL, shipDate ASC, createdDate ASC, SOID ASC`

        return query;
    }


    export default function PickingTerminal(props){
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
            { title: 'Printed', field: 'printed'},
            { title: 'Start Date', field: 'startDate', },
            { title: 'Pordcution Line', field: 'productionLine', },
            { title: 'Work Order', field: 'WOID', type: 'numeric'},
            { title: 'Part Name', field: 'partName', },
            { title: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity', type: 'numeric'},
            { title: 'Customer', field: 'customerName', },
            {title: 'Ship Date', field: 'shipDate'},
            { title: 'Production Status', field: 'productionStatus', },
        ]);
        const [work_orders, setWO] = useState([]);
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
     
        const getData =()=>{
            var query = {
                    'query' : getQuery()
                }
            var url =  'http://10.2.1.202:8000/api/pickingterminal?';
            Axios.post(url , query).then(result=>{
                console.log(result.data);
                setWO(result.data);
            })
        }
        React.useEffect(()=>{
            getData();
            console.log(work_orders);
        },[]);  

       const setColor=(rowData)=>{
            if(rowData['buildable'] < rowData['quantity']){
                return '#E52B50';
            }
            else if(rowData['expedite'] > 0){
                return '#FF7E00';
            }
            else if(rowData['productionNotes'].includes('RMA')){
                return 'green';
            }
            else if(rowData['productionNotes'].includes('NEW BUILD')){
                return 'deeppink';
            }
            return '#FFF';
        }
        
        const printItem=(rowData)=>{
            console.log(rowData);
        }
        
        const confirm = useConfirm();
        const handleShow = () => {
            setOpen(true);
            // console.log("handle show: " + open);
        };
        
        const handleClose = () => {
            setOpen(false);
            console.log("handle show: " + open);
        };

        return(
            <div>
                <MaterialTable
                options={{
                    sorting: true,
                    filtering: false,
                    search: true,
                    exportButton: true,
                    pageSize: 100,
                    pageSizeOptions: [25, 50, 100, 150],
                    thirdSortClick: true,
                    initialPage: 0,
                    debounceInterval: 500,
                    paging: true,
                    rowStyle: rowData=>({
                        backgroundColor: setColor(rowData)
                    })
                  }}
                
                onRowClick={(selectedRow) => handleShow()}
                columns={columns}
                data={work_orders}
                title="Work Orders"
                  />
                    <AlertDialog 
                    open={open}
                    handleClose={handleClose} />
            </div>
            
        );


    }
```

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
    import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
    import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
    import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
    import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

    export default function AlertDialog(props) {
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.open);
      const handleClose = () => {
        console.log('in change');
        props.handleClose();
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            open={props.open}
            onClose={props.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
                Google, even when no apps are running.
              </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={props.handleClose} color="primary">
                Disagree
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={props.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                Agree
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: I also found out seems like the setOpen can't update open immediately, not sure if it is the reason.

Comment: Additionally, here is the error message I got once it breaks. Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED

Answer (score 0):

as the dialog open and close state and also the handler is created and controlled by the parent component, so don't state and function inside the modal. just extract the prop and pass that prop to the modal.

```
import React from 'react';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
    import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
    import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
    import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
    import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

    export default function AlertDialog(props) {

      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            open={props.open}
            onClose={props.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
                Google, even when no apps are running.
              </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={props.handleClose} color="primary">
                Disagree
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={props.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                Agree
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method, it still breaks after open and close the modal only once.

Comment: ohk.. can you please reproduce your issue in a [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io).. It'll be helpful